# Can I create a chained SSL certificate that is recognized by browsers?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl-certificate, certificate

Let's say I have a certificate that is valid for example.com (and backed by a known SSL vendor). I want to be able to have a test version of the domain, test.example.com, that is also secured with an SSL certificate, but I'd like to do so without paying for a commercial certificate (I realize there are "free" certificates but nearly all of them come with time limitations, which doesn't work for me).

It's apparently possible to create a chained certificate off of that certificate. What I'm wondering is whether browsers will recognize that chained certificate as valid.

Note that the certificate for example.com is an SAN certificate and covers other domains like docs.example.com, example.org, etc.

Ideally I would like the chained certificate to *also* be an SAN certificate, and just provide test analogs of each domain: test.example.com, test.docs.example.com, test.example.org, etc.

I'm aware I'll need a separate IP address for the test certificate.

This is on Apache and CentOS, by the way.

Comment: You can perhaps hire the NSA to use top-flight mathematicians to invent new science and engineer a hash collision attack on the CA.  Alternatively, you can buy a wildcard cert.

Comment: A wildcard would not be sufficient. Sounds like I either create a self-signed CA certificate or buy another SAN certificate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What I'm wondering is whether browsers will recognize that chained certificate as valid.

None of them. Within your certificate, it has the entry under *Certificate Basic Constraints*:

```
Not Critical
Is not a Certification Authority
```

Once the browser sees that as an intermediate certificate, it'll reject the ones you 'sign' it with.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot issue more certificates off of your `example.com` certificate.  Check its x509 Basic Constraints field.  Every certificate that a trusted CA issues to a client should always have the `CA:FALSE` constraint (though recently, [a major CA admitted to issuing a certificate to a client with this restriction removed](http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/02/critics-slam-ssl-authority-for-minting-cert-used-to-impersonate-sites/)).

If you need to test with certificates that you craft, you'll need to make your own CA and trust it in the client browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have bought your certificate already then tough luck. If not, look at buying either a wildcard or putting Subject Alternative Name attribute in the CSR. Most CAs will happily sign it without charging you extra.

Comment: Note that the certificate I bought is great and perfect for my normal needs and needs no adjustment. I just need to either create a self-signed certificate or buy another SAN certificate (I'll probably go with the former).

Comment: Well, you asked for a cert that is recognized by browsers. Self-signed one is certainly not.

Comment: Yeah, I'll just have to tell all my testers to install the CA. Would have been nice to skip that step.